# Qt QWidgets C++ Как правильно отображать один виджет в разных окнах

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Я новичок в Qt. Пожалуйста, не ругайте.
У меня есть некая таблица `QTableWidget`, к которой подключены сигналы.
Она расположена в центральном виджете.
В зависимости от действия пользователя, эта таблица должна появляться в разных местах, то есть, на разных `QLayout`'тах.

Выглядит это примерно так: пользователю понадобилось изменить некоторый параметр в таблице, перед ним открылось окошко (или в `QStackedWidget` новый виджет) с этой же таблицой и элементы управления (кнопки и т. д). Затем, после редактирования, таблица должна отображаться в том же (центральном) окне.
*Создание новой таблицы не подходит, так как теряются все сигналы, да ещё и перезаполнять надо - дополнительные затраты.*

Вопрос:
Как правильно реализовать подобный функционал ?
Нужно каждый раз передавать владение с помощью `QLayout::insert`, а потом "возвращать" обратно в исходный виджет ?

Comment: Таблицу можно оставить одну. А вот данные для ее заполнения иметь разные. Когда надо изменить новый параметр просто очищаете таблицу и заполняете новыми данными из какой-нибудь модели, или объекта с данными

Comment: setParent чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: Лучше не использовать виджеты для хранения данных если их очень много, лучше хранить их отдельно, а таблицу использовать только для отображения, а доступ к данным осуществлять через так называемую "Модель". Это называется [Model-View-Controller](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)